# ReactJS - Detect third-party DOM insert using Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Inside the component, a third-party JavaScript library has injected some content into a specific DIV (`voice-service`) after React render. I wanted to add or remove some CSS class on that DIV (`voice-service`) when the DOM was injected using Mutation Observer, like -

When DOM injected -

```
<div id="maxVoiceContainer" class="voice-service service--active">
 // third-party content
</div>
```

When DOM Not injected -

```
<div id="maxVoiceContainer" class="voice-service service--inactive">
// third-party content
</div>
```

**heroVoice Component:**

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const heroVoice = (props) => {

    const elementRef = useRef();
    const [voiceAvailability, setVoiceAvailability] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const config = { attributes: false, characterData: false, childList: true, subtree: true, attributeOldValue: false, characterDataOldValue: false };
        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            mutations.forEach(mutation => {
                const newNodes = mutation.addedNodes;
                newNodes.forEach(node => {
                    if (node.classList && node.classList.contains('pocket-sphinx-container')) {
                        setVoiceAvailability(status => !status);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        observer.observe(elementRef.current, config);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div
            ref={elementRef}
            id="maxVoiceContainer"
            className={`voice-service ${voiceAvailability ? ' service--active' : 'service--inactive'}`}
        >
          // third-party content
        </div>
    );
}

export default heroVoice;
```

Wanted to know -

1. Do I need to disconnect the observer?
2. Looks good? best practices?
3. Also, I do not want to re-render when the state was updated!

Answer (score 1):

Q: Do I need to disconnect the observer?
It's not needed directly, but I recommand it with the [`mutationObserver.disconnect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/disconnect)  Method, because you is called One time on ComponentDidMount.
An empty Array at the second parameter means it.
[Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Looks good? best practices?
Yes looks quite good. Avoid nested forEach. Better use first a map and than an forEach

```js
 mutations.map(mutation => mutation.addedNodes).forEach(node => {
  if (node.classList && node.classList.contains('pocket-sphinx-container')) {
    setVoiceAvailability(status => !status);
  }
 });
```

Also, I do not want to re-render when the state was updated!
React's lifecycle is build for this. There are two possibilities. First, you can use Redux or you make a local variable which is being setted in the forEach. But generally don't use a setState hook in a forEach

Comment: thnks. any suggestion for placing disconnect method on my above example?

Comment: after everything was observed. I don't know what exactly your are fetching but you can set a Timeout which disconnect after 5000ms